# wglMakeCurrent fails with 1282

Tags: c++, opengl

I am creating a visual studio Win32 application using OpenGL. However when I call glewInit and then GetLastError(), I get error 127 ("The specified procedure could not be found.") I am statically linking to opengl as follows:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>
#include <wglew.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>

// link with libraries
#pragma comment(lib, "openGL32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32s.lib")
```

My guess is that for some reason at run-time my application can't find the function but I'm not sure why and it's driving me nuts. I've tried placing the libraries directly in the executable directory but have had no luck. Here is the offending code:

```
      // create a device context
  m_deviceContext = GetDC(m_windowHandle);

  // choose a pixel format
  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
  memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(pfd));

  pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
  pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW; // double-buffering, opengl, and render to window
  pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  pfd.cColorBits = 32; // 32 bits of color information (the higher, the more colors)
  pfd.cDepthBits = 32; // 32 bits of color information (the higher, the more depth levels)
  pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

  int pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(m_deviceContext, &pfd);
  assert(pixelFormat);

  // set the pixel format
  BOOL res = SetPixelFormat(m_deviceContext, pixelFormat, &pfd);
  assert(res);

  // this creates an openGL 2.1 context for the device context
  HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(m_deviceContext);
  wglMakeCurrent(m_deviceContext, tempContext);

  // enable GLEW so we can try to create a 3.2 context instead
  DWORD error = GetLastError();
  GLenum err = glewInit();
  error = GetLastError();
  assert(err == GLEW_OK);
```

Some specifics about my setup. I altered my Working Directory to be where the executable is generated (($ProjectDir)\Binaries\Win32). *Before this things worked fine*. I tried adding additional dependencies and altering the additional library directories with no luck.

What am I missing for my program to find the glewInit procedure? I appreciate any help or suggestions.

EDIT: glGetError() returns 1282 (INVALID_OPERATION) after making this call to wglMakeCurrent():

```
  // attempt to create the opengl 3.2 context
  int attr[] = {
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
    WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
    0
  };

  if(wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context") == 1)
  {
    CheckOpenGLError();
    m_renderContext = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(m_deviceContext, NULL, attr);
    CheckOpenGLError();
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    CheckOpenGLError();   // <-- This guy calls glGetError() and returns 1282
    wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
    CheckOpenGLError();
    wglMakeCurrent(m_deviceContext, m_renderContext);
  }
```

What I thought was the problem was not. It looks like instead my problem is that this call to wglMakeCurrent is failing, and I am unable to render to my window. After doing some research, the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) suggests that it is perfectly valid to call with NULL as the HDC because it is ignored, and the rendering context should be made not current.

New Question: What reasons might there be for wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL) to fail? I've tried wglMakeCurrent(m_deviceContext, NULL) as well just in case, but it failed as well.

Comment: What makes you think it didn't find the glewInit procedure? You don't load that at runtime at all. Does `glewInit()` actually return an error? I've never checked this, but `glewInit()` triggering `GetLastError()` to return some not resolved symbol error might be perfectly normal, als `glewInit()` is going to query lots of function pointers which are unlikely to be present on your system.

Comment: I see. The glewInit() function itself is returning GLEW_OK, so that might not be the problem then. I did some more digging, and found that glGetError() doesn't return an error code until wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL) is called. I added some more code above related to this.

Comment: What is the issue you are actually trying to solve here?

Comment: Checking for GL errors while no GL context is current is undefined behavior. On windows, this will always return `GL_INVALID_VALUE` . It is still unclear what your problem with that is.

Comment: You can check if `wglMakeCurrent()` fails by checking its return value. And in case of an error, window's GetLastError() should report the reasons. I don't know what your real issue is, but I think you are on the wrong track with this question so far.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it has pointed me in a different direction. I'll need to do some more research and rethink my question if I post again. wglMakeCurrent is returning TRUE but glGetError returns 1282 in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am creating a visual studio Win32 application using OpenGL. However when I call glewInit and then GetLastError(), I get error 127 ("The specified procedure could not be found.")

It's been a long known issue that GLEW may leave OpenGL in a errornous state after initialization. Ignore it. The idiomatic way of initializing GLEW is

```
if( GLEW_OK != glewInit() ) {
    handle_glew_init_error_condition();
}
else {
    /* flush the OpenGL error state, ignoring all errors */
    while( GL_NO_ERROR != glGetError() );
}
```

Note that you must call glGetError in a loop, because it's allowed to have multiple error conditions be set and glGetError reports and clears them only one after another.

> I am statically linking to opengl as follows:

Certainly not. `.lib` files can also be used for dynamic linking; in that case they contain the name of the DLL and the table of entry points.

---

#### Update regarding wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL)

Once you unbound the OpenGL context, what error state is glGetError supposed to report from? There's no OpenGL context it could work with, so it's reporting you that. glGetError itself is performing an invalid operation, because you call it without a OpenGL context being active.

Comment: I since solved my problem, turned out to be unrelated to glewInit and wglMakeCurrent. I was dumb and my exe didn't have a path to my shader files so it failed to render. I had no idea glewInit and glError worked that way, certainly helps me understand the behavior I was seeing. Thank you.